# Number of cycles taken for C++ or ANSI C?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, processor

Is there anywhere on the web where i can get an idea of what the various programming language syntax take in terms of processor (Core i7 and Core 2) cycles? At university i learnt the ARM assembly language and we could map the number of cycles taken to do a subtraction operator etc. I just wondered if its possible to do this with a higher level language on the Core i7 or Core 2?

Comment: A more accurate way would be to read the assembly generated by your compiler. Then you're left with the problem of predicting the performance of a piece of code on a modern out-of-order processor.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Maybe we can help you solve a problem you're trying to figure out.

Comment: Is there a way in VS2010 to see the assembly produced?

Comment: You have to go into project settings and turn on generation of assembly listings for each individual source file.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. That's completely dependent on the compiler you use, and what optimization settings you use, etc.

You can use your favorite compiler and settings to generate assembly code, and from the assembly code you can make these kinds of predictions.

However, remember that on modern architectures things like memory latency and register renaming have large effects on speed, and these effects are not obvious even from inspection of the assembly code.

Comment: And good luck with 64-bit architecture, x86 is small fries compared to that nightmare.

Comment: Most of the time, slow code is due to slow CPU instructions (e.g. integer divisions or transcendental floating point operations), cache misses, and branch mispredictions. You can deduce all those, and get the general idea of performance, from looking at the code.

Comment: @user: Yes, but you're not going to get anything like a "feature x == y cycles"

Answer (score 2):

In general, in higher-level languages, individual statements don't map cleanly onto specific sequences of machine-code instructions.  The compiler will typically optimise things, which will involve various transformations, arrangements, and even eliminations, of instructions.  Therefore, it's not usually meaningful to quote metrics like "a `for` expression takes 20 cycles".

Answer (score 2):

You have to map higher level instructions into assembly instructions manually, or look at the assembly listing. And then look here

http://gmplib.org/~tege/x86-timing.pdf

or here

http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/248966.pdf